# How to adjust the height of slides in Slick slideshow to be equal?

Tags: css, slick.js

Please take a look [here](https://www.sergiosdorje.com/) - more specifically to the testimonial slider in the violet background.
I am using a Slick slider to display the thumbnails. All seems to be working fine, however the testimonials have text of different lengths which influences the height of the container.

I would like to have the container to always be the same height, which means it should be the height of the highest testimonial.

Here is the code I am using:

```js
  $(".quotes").slick({
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    speed: 1200,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: false,
  });
```

```css
    .home-quote {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 450px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 80px 12%;
      .quote-block {
        font: Italic 40px/60px "Libre Baskerville";
        color: $bluedark;
        position: relative;
        .quote-text {
          &::before {
            content: "„";
            position: absolute;
            top: -116px;
            left: -100px;
            font: Bold 150px/65px "Libre Baskerville";
            color: $violet;
          }
          &::after {
            content: "„";
            position: absolute;
            right: -100px;
            font: Bold 150px/65px "Libre Baskerville";
            color: $violet;
          }
        }
    
        footer {
          position: relative;
          margin-top: 60px;
          cite {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And here is a sample testimonial's HTML:

```html
       <section  class="testimonials">
            <div role="complementary" class="carousel simple quotes no-fouc">
            <blockquote>
            <cite>M.</cite>
                <p>Short text</p>
            </blockquote>
            <blockquote>
            <cite>A.</cite>
                <p>Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text A.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <blockquote>
            <cite>M.</cite>
             <p>Short text</p>
            </blockquote>
    
            </div>
        </section>
```

Can anyone help please to remove the resizing of those divs?

Comment: height:100% does not work for the container they are in ?

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this:

```
.simple cite {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
  .slick-track {
    display:flex;
  }

.carousel {
    height:inherit;
  }
```

That should work fine.